# Symfony 4 PHPunit, not truncating tables in SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I am trying to setup a simple test in PPHunit in my Symfony 4.4 app, but it seems that the test database (SQLite) is not truncating.

So it will work the first time you run it, but not after that as the auto increment column id is not resetting.

It's strange as this was working for me on another project until very recently:

```
// tests/BaseWebTestCase.php

protected function tearDown(): void
{
    parent::tearDown();

    $purger = new ORMPurger($this->em);
    $purger->setPurgeMode(ORMPurger::PURGE_MODE_TRUNCATE); 
    $purger->purge();
}
```

But maybe a recent update has meant it doesn't work anymore. How can I update this so that the tables are truncated every time my test is run?

When I run the test I get the following error:

```
There was 1 error:    

1) App\Tests\Controller\BlogPostControllerTest::testAUserCanAccessBlogPost
Error: Call to a member function getId() on null

/home/vagrant/code/tests/Controller/BlogPostControllerTest.php:26

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

This is my test:

```
// tests/Controller/BlogPostControllerTest.php

public function testAUserCanAccessBlogPost()
{
    $blogPost = $this->em
        ->getRepository(BlogPost::class)
        ->findOneBy([
            'id' => rand(1, 20)
        ]);

    $this->client->request('GET', '/' . $blogPost->getId());

    $this->assertEquals(200, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
}
```

And the fixtures function:

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $faker = Factory::create('en_GB');

    // Create blog posts
    for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
        $blogPost = new BlogPost();
        $blogPost->setTitle($faker->sentence(3));
        $blogPost->setBody($faker->paragraph);
        $manager->persist($blogPost);
    }

    $manager->flush();
}
```

If I add a die statement to the test I am able to login to the SQLite database and I can see that the ids for the posts are incrementing and not resetting to start with 1, which is causing the error.

UPDATE

I am now able to get this working if I clear the cache:

```
sudo rm -rf var/cache
```

The test will work once, but fail if I run a second time, hence the original issue remains.

Comment: You don't have any error ? What happens if you use the doctrine:fixtures:load with --purge-with-truncate ?

Comment: Yes I am getting errors as the test is unable to find the ids. I will update the original question

Comment: I was talking about an error related to the purge, the error you show is caused by the id not existing in the table, so the object is null. Beside, why do you use random ?
And what about the purge with the command "doctrine:fixtures:load --purge-with-truncate" ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, `bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --purge-with-truncate --env=test` does reset the ids in sqlite, however I would prefer this to happen within my test setup. Also fixtures are loaded within the test environment setup function. I use random to ensure a random post is selected from the fixtures, but am happy to hear suggestions for improvement :)